# How to update dependent key values in redis?

Tags: redis, lua

I would like to know if there is a recommended mechanism for updating one or more keys, based on the values of others, should those values change.

This is kind of like properties, or getters and setters, but for redis keys.

**Why do I need this?**

Suppose I have perhaps multiple (10-100 in my case) clients that all need to know a value `dep1` which is a (pure) function of `indep1`, ... , `indepN`. One way to do this is have all the clients watch for changes in `indep1`, ... , `indepN`, and calculate the value of `dep1`. This seems to me to duplicate work, and increase network traffic. However, if `dep1` is "automatically" updated, they all only need to listen for changes to `dep1`.

**Current Thinking**

The only solution I can think of is to have one monitoring client, that does this work. However, I am wondering if there is a better way. Perhaps with Lua. I am a complete Redis and Lua noob by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lua seems like a decent idea. You could use Lua scripts for updating any of `indep1` ... `indepN` and the scripts can automatically calculate `dep1` and set its value in the database, in a single transaction (a Lua script runs to completion before any other commands are processed). Reading `dep1` is then guaranteed to be correct as it was updated atomically alongside any of `indepX`. You would then only need to watch for keyspace changes on `dep1` in your client.

Note: this may not be the most efficient way to do this, as the calculations for determining `dep1` may be expensive and duplicated any time one of `indepX` is updated.